# JsReport using C# .NET core and Vs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, entity-framework-core, jsreport

I am trying to learn JsReport using c# and .NET core and visual studio. I have installed the required nuget packages (jsreport.binary and jsreport.Local). I am trying to replicate the code found  [Here](https://jsreport.net/learn/dotnet-local). The problem is that I keep getting the following error.

```
***Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3021 Unable to copy file "C:\Users\jmodiba\source\repos\js\js\obj\Debug\net6.0\apphost.exe" to "bin\Debug\net6.0\js.exe". Access to the path 'bin\Debug\net6.0\js.exe' is denied.    js  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   5097***
```

here is the code,

```
using jsreport.Binary;
using jsreport.Local;
using jsreport.Types;

var rs = new LocalReporting().UseBinary(JsReportBinary.GetBinary()).AsUtility().Create();

await rs.RenderAsync(new RenderRequest()
{
    Template = new Template()
    {
        Recipe = Recipe.ChromePdf,
        Engine = Engine.None,
        Content = "Hello from pdf"
    }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like the file is in use

Comment: Hello, I have tested according to the information you provided and there is no error as you said. So it might not be a problem with the code. First of all, please make sure that the JsReport you are using is the latest stable version, and you also need to use .net 6.0. If all of these are fine, then there may be a folder permissions issue and you want to open access to the folder. In the end, there may be a problem of thread occupation. For example, you can go to the task manager to end test.exe. Of course, there are many reasons for thread occupation. Can you provide the MSBuildScript code?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT, I am using the latest version of JsReport and .NET 6.0. I changed permission setting for the folder and i also tried changing the directory. But all of this didnt work. by MSBuildScript code do you mean the .csproj file

Comment: I managed to solve the access permission issue and the code is running without any error but I am still not getting the pdf output

Comment: @JacobModiba What error did you report when using JsReport to output pdf?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT. At first it was access denied. But i managed to sort that out. at the moment the code is running without any error but i am not getting any output.

Comment: @JacobModiba This situation is rare. Please check if you have permission to save the pdf folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the problem. My antivirus kept on moving the .exe file created to quarantine. Once I created an exception in the antivirus setting my code ran correctly.